# Sitecore workflow template questions

Tags: templates, workflow, sitecore

Currently I am trying to find a way to have a template that is used across a shared environment capable of having a different workflow in use for each environment.

For example say I have a bike template shared between sites, I have one site that stocks the bike in a warehouse and a separate site that is a store front to sell the bike. The approval process will be different for these sites, the warehouse will simply go from Draft > Published whereas the store front wants to check over the details before displaying to the customer so they use a Draft > Pending Approval > Publish workflow.

Say I already have a bunch of bikes defined in both sites, how can I make a change so that for each different site a different workflow is used by the bikes. If possible I would like to avoid a solution that requires code.

I am guessing that I will need to duplicate the templates and have a separate one for each site (e.g. WH Bike and Sales Bike) which isn't really ideal either as this means lots of manual fixing of the existing workflow values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a separate workflow, it sounds like you just need a separate stage and action that is only available to your store front.

For example, your single workflow might look like this:

**Stage 1: Draft**

Actions:

- Submit for Approval (secured to Store Front)
- Submit for Publish (secured to Warehouse)

**Stage 2: Pending Approval**

- Secured to Store Front, so as not to be visible to Warehouse

**Stage 3: Publish**

If the only difference is the stages, you can definitely go with security to use a single workflow and flow users through their own actions and stages.

Answer (score 1):

Reworked my answer:

You can approach this by using the sitecore rules engine.

You can take a look at [DYNAMIC WORKFLOW](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Dynamic_Workflow.aspx) module in the Sitecore Marketplace.

It should allow you to create the rules and execute the start workflow action.

Taken from the module documentation:

> Start workflow – moves item into a specified workflow and starts the
>   workflow process. Example: a landing workflow used when item gets
>   created but a specific workflow should be applied depending on item
>   location in the content tree.

Comment: would this work only for newly added items only though? Or would it apply the rules to already existing items?